# Two custom post types divided in two columns inside a bootstrap carousel

Tags: custom-post-types, twitter-bootstrap, slideshow

Im trying to use the Bootstrap carousel to show some custom posts in my page, something like in the image below

[image]

But right now, my carousel only show the same post twice, like the image below
[image]

Heres my code:

```
            <?php $args = array('post_type' => 'cases', 'order' => 'DESC', 'orderby' => 'date', 'posts_per_page' => '-1');
            $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

            if( $the_query->have_posts() ):?>   
            <?php  $index = 0; ?>

                <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
                  <!-- Indicators -->
                  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                  </ol>

                  <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
                <article class="container">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="carousel-inner">
                            <?php while( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>
                                <div class="item<?php if ($index == 1) { echo ' active'; } ?>">
                                    <div class="col-md-6">
                                        <?php  
                                            $imagem_personalizada = get_field('capa_da_pagina_do_case');
                                            $thumb_capa = wp_get_attachment_image_src($imagem_personalizada, 'capaIdeia');
                                        ?>
                                        <a href="<?php the_permalink();  ?>" style="text-decoration: none;">
                                            <br>
                                            <div id="secao-titulo-ideia-single" class="nopadding">
                                                <img  class="img-responsive center-block" src="<?php echo $thumb_capa[0]; ?>" alt="Thumb Post" width="100%">
                                                <h2 class="brandonregular titulo-ideia-single text-center"> <?php  the_field('titulo_do_case'); ?> </h2>
                                            </div>
                                        </a>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-6">
                                        <a href="<?php the_permalink();  ?>" style="text-decoration: none;">
                                            <div class="nopadding">
                                                <img  class="img-responsive center-block" src="<?php echo $thumb_capa[0]; ?>" alt="Thumb Post" width="100%">
                                                <h2 class="brandonregular"> <?php  the_field('titulo_do_case'); ?> </h2>
                                            </div>
                                        </a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            <?php $index++; ?>
                            <?php endwhile; ?>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </article>
                </div>
            <?php endif; ?>
            <?php wp_reset_query(); wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

I don't know why is this happenning, I've tried many diferent things, but I can't find a way to solve this.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You're displaying the same post twice every iteration of the loop! There'll be 2,2,3,3,4,4 etc rather than 2,3,4,5. Perhaps you've muddled up slides and posts?

Comment: Hi Tom! Thanks for the comment. 
I noticed that now, but I don't know how to change that, perhaps I should create one loop for each column?

Comment: You don't need two loops. Outside your loop, put the carousel container divs/tags. Then do a foreach loop inside, so you only output individual slide divs/tags during the loop, Then once you end the loop, add the closing carousel container divs/tags.

Comment: @WebElaine I tried to use the answer from Picard and it worked really well for me, but anyway, thanks for your tip. Now I understand what I was doing wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this.

The idea is to check within the loop if the item is even or odd, and for the odd item you open the two-item-slide (display the opening HTML), where for the even you close it.

I haven't tested it but the idea is like this:

```
<article class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="carousel-inner">
            <?php 
                $cnt = 1;
                while( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>

                <!-- code for the first item in slide -->
                <?PHP if ($cnt % 2): ?>
                <div class="item<?php if ($cnt == 1) { echo ' active'; } ?>">
                <?PHP endif; ?>

                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <?php  
                            $imagem_personalizada = get_field('capa_da_pagina_do_case');
                            $thumb_capa = wp_get_attachment_image_src($imagem_personalizada, 'capaIdeia');
                        ?>
                        <a href="<?php the_permalink();  ?>" style="text-decoration: none;">
                            <br>

                            <!-- code for the first item in slide -->
                            <?PHP if ($cnt % 2): ?>
                            <div id="secao-titulo-ideia-single" class="nopadding">
                            <!-- code for the second item in slide -->
                            <?PHP else: ?>
                            <div class="nopadding">
                            <?PHP endif; ?>

                                <img  class="img-responsive center-block" src="<?php echo $thumb_capa[0]; ?>" alt="Thumb Post" width="100%">

                                <!-- code for the first item in slide -->
                                <?PHP if ($cnt % 2): ?>
                                <h2 class="brandonregular titulo-ideia-single text-center"> <?php  the_field('titulo_do_case'); ?> </h2>
                                <!-- code for the second item in slide -->
                                <?PHP else: ?>
                                <h2 class="brandonregular"> <?php  the_field('titulo_do_case'); ?> </h2>
                                <?PHP endif; ?>
                            </div>
                        </a>
                </div>
                <!-- code for the second item in slide -->
                <?PHP if (!($cnt % 2)): ?>
                </div>
                <?PHP endif; ?>

            <?php $cnt++; ?>
            <?php endwhile; ?>

            <!-- code for closing the slide if only one item in the last slide -->
            <?PHP if (!($cnt % 2)): ?>
            </div>
            <?PHP endif; ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</article>
```

Comment: Hello Picard, thanks for finding a bit of time to help me! It worked perfectly. This is exactly what I need! And now I understand what I was doing wrong! Big thanks for your patience! =)

Comment: If this is the answer you were looking for, why couldn't you mark it as the answer.
This helps other to find the working solution for the issue. @RafaelDantas